# Iterate through all elements using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, iterator, web-scraping

I currently have a script that can find the first element with the link text "Toast" using

```
toast_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Toast')
```

The problem I am having is that there are multiple instances of the link text "Toast" and I would like to iterate through all of them. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find multiple elements, use `find_elements_*` instead of `find_element_*` (NOTE: `s`):

```
toast_links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Toast')
for link in toast_links:
    ....
```

Comment: Didn't know that was a possibility, I guess I read over it when I was looking it up. Thanks, this was quite easy!